# Bootstrap 3 rows and css :before property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Smartix/98sdrnkk/

The `:before` css property doesn't seem to work on a bootstrap row.

In the example above a centered red line should be displayed in the bacground of the div with class `myline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply your :after pseudo class to this rule instead (after col-xs-12) :

```
<div class="row myline">
        <div class="col-xs-12 myline">
            <p>A red line should appear in the background of this row</p>
            <p>The line should span from the top of the row...</p>
            <p>... till here. Why is there no line?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/98sdrnkk/2/)**

or just add a height value and it will work properly :

```
.myline:before {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;    
    width: 4px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/98sdrnkk/3/)**

Comment: First problem: In my actual page I will have many "col" divs... Specifically, after the div with class="row" I will have a variable number of divs with class "col-xs-6" (let's say 8). Just to be clear: 1 row with 8 col divs inside. Second problem: in your fiddle the line is on top of the divs and not in background.

Comment: because bootstrap allready use them and aplly a display table to them !!

Comment: Ok!! Thanks... wait 1 minute.. I would like to submit a possible solution and hear your opinion... but I need to change the fiddle.

Comment: I managed to explain everything in this comment. The question is about rows and cols in bootstrap. Look at this sequence of divs: "container" > my div with class "myline" > "row" > "col". Is it wrong to use this div sequence? Does "row" need to be a DIRECT child of "container"? And what about this other possibility? "container" > "row" > "myline" > "col"

Comment: my bad finly it works look at the edit it was because the hight of your befor was 0px !!

Comment: No, I can't use height because I don't know the height of my div (it's variable). Please look at my previous comment. If I add another div with class "myline" it works BUT I don't know if I can use the div sequence presented above